# How can I filter out specific columns in a ndarray?

Tags: multidimensional-array, rust

If you want specific columns in NumPy, you can do `data[:, columnslist]`. For example, if you want columns 1 and 9

```py
data[:, [1, 9]]
```

How can I do this using Rust's ndarray? I have gone through [`ndarray` for NumPy users](https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.12.1/ndarray/doc/ndarray_for_numpy_users/index.html), but they don't have any similar example. Below is what I tried.

```
let a = arr2(&[[1., 2., 3.], [4., 5., 6.]]);
let b = stack(Axis(0), &[a.column(1).view(), a.column(2).view()]).unwrap();
let b = Array::from_iter(b.iter());
let b = b.reshape((2, 2));
```

which gives the error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `ndarray::OwnedRepr<&{float}>: ndarray::data_traits::DataShared` is not satisfied
   --> src/main.rs:143:15
    |
143 |     let b = b.reshape((2,2));
    |               ^^^^^^^ the trait `ndarray::data_traits::DataShared` is not implemented for `ndarray::OwnedRepr<&{float}>`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the ndarray docs](https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.12.1/ndarray/struct.ArrayBase.html#method.reshape), `reshape` can only be used on an `ArcArray`. For any other array, use `into_shape`:

```
let b = b.into_shape((2, 2));
```